# .htaccess - redirect to same path from domain A to domain B - polish letters in domain name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How I can redirect using .htaccess file from domain: testÓwka.net to domain testOwka.net with saving URL path?

For example, when user visit website: testówka.net/login, I want to redirect this user to: testowka.net/login.

I tried in that way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testówka\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://ofertowka.net%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

and in that way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xn\-\-testwka\-o0a\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://testowka.net%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

I tried with escape and without but nothing work fine. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modify your rewrite to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xn--testwka-o0a\.net [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://testowka.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```